# Runing multiple processes within python script

Tags: python, subprocess

Within my python script I need to launch several processes :
1) I need to run another python script ( a flask app with the command `python app.py`)
2)then I need to launch the command `ngrok http 5000` and from this command output get the url on which ngrok is forwarding.

I have tried to use the `subprocess` module, but when it executes :

```
subprocess.Popen( "python app/app.py",shell=True)
```

it launches the interactive shell and blocks the execution of my script.

What is the correct way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just instead of `Popen` function, should to use the `call` function.

```
subprocess.call('python app.py', shell=True)
```

Also see the documentation [subprocess docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)